# Listbox add xml

Tags: xml, delphi, listbox

I need your help.
I have two Listbox

In Listbox1 i have (Language.id  (:integer) (1,2,3... etc)

In Listbox2 i have (Language.name (:string) (England, Germany, ... etc)

I want to add them all to xml. Everyone Listbox item Index new my Languages. Just like below, only one line I can not write.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
   lNewLanguage := XMLIntf.Languages.add;
   lNewLanguage.id   := listbox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex];
   lNewLanguage.name := listbox2.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex];
  i:= 0;
  while (i < ListBox1.Count) and(i < ListBox2.Count) do
  begin

     ListBox1.Items[i] + Listbox2.Items[i];   //This line

    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: that line is supposed to add two fields and put the result some where. your  problem is the 'some where'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i:= 0;
  while (i < ListBox1.Count) and(i < ListBox2.Count) do
  begin
    lNewLanguage := XMLIntf.Languages.add;
    lNewLanguage.id   := listbox1.Items[i];
    lNewLanguage.name := listbox2.Items[i];
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

But to be honest, this is not too sensible. If you press the button twice you will get every entry twice...

Comment: Thank you very much. Fact,I need to be careful, I'm learning. Do you have a better idea? Please show me

Comment: You just need to clear your XML list first - I imagine XMLIntf.Languages.Clear just after i := 0; would do the job, but have not tried it.

Comment: It is not a solution. Because I'm working on data. But I have an idea, button.Enabled: = false . Again thank you very much :)

Comment: @JohnnyBlady Perhaps you're missing the point. What does working on data have to do with not being able to clear an XML node? That's precisely what will be needed.